# wpf Multiple dispatch timer for timer application : Run multiple timer simulteniously

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

**Read multiple stackoverflow, codeproject solution, could not integrate to my problem.**

Have a datagrid in a usercontrol which is loaded in a window. Each DataRow in the DataGrid represents a timer setting.

Like:

```
timer name  : Test 1 , Timer : 1h 3m
timer name  : Test 2 , Timer : 2h 2m
timer name  : Test 3 , Timer : 3h 1m
```

Selecting a row, clicking on the button Start, Starts the timer of that row. And with dispatcher tick event, it updates the grid I have done till this. Now I have to start another(or two or ...) timer which will do the same at the same time. I am stuck on this. Let me share what I have tried!

**btnStartClickEvent in mainwindow.xaml.cs**

```
if (btnStart.Content.ToString() == "Start")
        {
            if (_AUC == ActiveUserControl.Grid)
            {
                runningRow = (TaskGridData)_TG.dgEmployee.SelectedItem;
                if (runningRow != null)
                {
                    currentlyRunningID.Add(runningRow.ID);
                    btnStart.Content = "Stop";
                    //worker.RunWorkerAsync(runningRow);
                    StartTimer(runningRow);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (btnStart.Content.ToString() == "Stop")
        {
            btnStart.Content = "Start";
            StopTimer();

        }
 private DateTime TimerStart { get; set; }
    private void StartTimer(TaskGridData tgd)
    {
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        TimerStart = DateTime.Now;
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
        //worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        //string etime = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentValue = DateTime.Now - TimerStart;
        runningRow.Duration = DurationValueToString(currentValue);
        temp = (List<TaskGridData>)_TG.dgEmployee.ItemsSource;
        foreach (TaskGridData item in temp)
        {
            if (item.ID == runningRow.ID)
            {
                item.Duration = DurationValueToString(DurationStringToVlaue(item.Duration) - DurationStringToVlaue(runningRow.Duration));
                break;
            }
        }
        //_TG.dgEmployee.ItemsSource = null;
        //_TG.dgEmployee.ItemsSource = temp;
        Thread NewThreadforStartProcessAfterTraining = new Thread(() => UpdateGrid());
        NewThreadforStartProcessAfterTraining.IsBackground = true;
        NewThreadforStartProcessAfterTraining.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        NewThreadforStartProcessAfterTraining.Start();

    }
    private void UpdateGrid()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            _TG.dgEmployee.ItemsSource = null;
            _TG.dgEmployee.ItemsSource = temp;
        }));

    }
```

I know this code is for single timer. If I click a 2nd row and try to start timer, then it gets error in tick event, `running row` is found null.

I am wondering how can I keep this code and make it work for multiple timer. May be multithreading. A guide to do that, will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thread NewThreadforStartProcessAfterTraining = new Thread(() => UpdateGrid());
    NewThreadforStartProcessAfterTraining.IsBackground = true;
    NewThreadforStartProcessAfterTraining.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    NewThreadforStartProcessAfterTraining.Start();
```

All the above part where you start a new STA thread is unneeded and wrong in this context, since you can't update the visual tree in this way. 
You can find a correct example of using a STA thread in one of my previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42473167/6996876

Try to understand the concept of thread affinity in WPF.

You simply need an `UpdateGrid()` where you have to delegate UI work to the dispatcher.

Furthermore,  passing an argument to the `Tick` event is already explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16380663/6996876
In your case you may want to change the current unique `runningRow` so that it's passed to the event instead.

Comment: I tried to add my `UpgradeGrid() ` method in the backgroundworker_dowork event. and upgrade the datagrid in background. but while i tried that way, it becomes not updatable.

Comment: Because you don't do *all UI work* there in the *dispatcher*. Read my answer well.